# Fluent NHibernate to an in-memory SQLite DB throws exceptions on insert with Version

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency, fluent-nhibernate

I've a rather large domain-model that persists using fluent NHibernate to MS SQL Server 2008.

Recently we've been running into concurrency problems, so I implemented Versioning NHibernate's excellent Version with an eye to using MSSQL's `timestamp`datatype. All my entities subclass the cunningly named `DomainEntity`abstract class, which has the following `IAutoMappingOverride`:

```
public class DomainEntityOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<DomainEntity> {
    public void Override(AutoMapping<DomainEntity> mapping) {
        mapping.OptimisticLock.Version();
        mapping.Version(entity => entity.Version);
    }
}
```

Furthermore I set up the versioning using an `IVersionConvention`:

```
public class VersionConvention : IVersionConvention {
    public void Apply(IVersionInstance instance) {
        instance.Column("Version");
        instance.Generated.Always();
        instance.UnsavedValue("null");
        instance.Not.Nullable();
        instance.CustomSqlType("timestamp");
    }
}
```

My understanding is that this should cause the Version to always be generated, and checked for concurrency issues. In my dev and production environments (both using MSSQL2008) it seems to work, but my in-memory tests using SQLite no longer work.

A basic test that now fails is the following:

```
    [Test(Description = "Can save an aircraft and it is persisted")]
    public void PersistAircraft_NewAircraft_AircraftIsPersisted() {
        var id = saveEntity(_aircraft); //exception thrown here

        var persisted = getEntity<Aircraft>(id);

        Assert.That(persisted.Registration, Is.EqualTo(_aircraftRegistration));
        Assert.That(persisted.Remarks, Is.EqualTo(_aircraftRemark));
    }
```

I get the follwing exception:

```
Test 'NOIS.Persistence.Tests.InMemory.AircraftPersistenceTest.PersistAircraft_NewAircraft_AircraftIsPersisted' failed: NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not insert: [NOIS.Model.Entities.AircraftType#9c2809ea-c0c5-4778-838b-9e2500a6d2ef][SQL: INSERT INTO "AircraftType" (ProducedBy, Active, Remarks, Name, Code, Category_id, Id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
----> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : Abort due to constraint violation
AircraftType.Version may not be NULL
```

at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
 at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
 at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute()
 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
 at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
 at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
 at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
 at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
 at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit()
 FluentlyConfiguredInMemoryDatabaseTest.cs(49,0): at NOIS.Persistence.Tests.FluentlyConfiguredInMemoryDatabaseTest.saveEntity(DomainEntity entity)
 InMemory\AircraftPersistenceTest.cs(33,0): at NOIS.Persistence.Tests.InMemory.AircraftPersistenceTest.PersistAircraft_NewAircraft_AircraftIsPersisted()
 --SQLiteException
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
 at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
 at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
 at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you are doing here.

But as I understand, you are using an SQL Server feature, this timestamps, which are not available in Sqlite. So it doesn't work there.

As far as I know, timestamps are set by Sql Server when inserting or updating records. They are not under control of NH. But NH supports them, with the trade off that it needs to get its value back from the database after inserting or updating. You need a good reason to use timestamps with NHibernate.

You don't need this SqlServer stuff to get NH's optimistic locking mechanism to work. It is actually fully managed by NH and doesn't require anything special from the database. Just define a integer column and property and map it as the entities version. Everything else is done be NH. I never had to use anything else.

Comment: I second this one, as per this discussion: http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/8cc36aa83b046810/94ce8a7e92943993?lnk=gst&q=sqlite#94ce8a7e92943993

Comment: Yes, I see that. What I gain with a timestamp is that row updates from other systems automatically update the timestamp column. In my DomainEntity the Version property is a byte[].

Comment: Just to add on - I have now tried to change the CustomSqlType to "int", and the same error occurs. I do not think this NOT NULL constraint comes from the datatype.

Comment: you should not just make the database datatype int. It should also be an int property which is mapped as version, not as property. I don't know how it looks in fluent, but there is a version tag for xml mapping.

Comment: Of course you still have a not null constraint when you just switch from timestamp to int. You will even have it on sql server, because the column won't be get any values anymore. You need to tell NH to fill the value by mapping it as version.

Comment: What I'm considering now is just removing the Version property from the fluent.NHibernate configuration in the setup of the test. It's not what I'm testing, and I really want to keep the timestamp datatype in the production system for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: I ended up following your original suggestion and going with an int column. I like the functionality of the timestamp datatype in sql server, but it did bind me too hard to that particular version of that particular database. Thanks for you input!